# Awk pattern matching and handling missing fields

Tags: awk

I have some data from an output of ldapsearch that looks like this:

```
> echo "$OUTPUT"
sn: name1
uid: uname1
mail: user1@mail.com
roomNumber: e2

sn: name2
uid: uname2
mail: user2@mail.com
roomNumber: e2

sn: name3
uid: uname3
roomNumber: e2

sn: name4
uid: uname4
mail: user4@mail.com
roomNumber: e2
```

I'm using awk to process each user into a single line so that it ends up like this:

```
name1|uname1|user1@mail.com|e2
name2|uname2|user2@mail.com|e2
name3|uname3||e2
name4|uname4|user4@mail.com|e2
```

The trouble is my code below can't handle the missing mail attribute, so it reuses the variable from the previous user and looks like this:

```
name1|uname1|user1@mail.com|e2
name2|uname2|user2@mail.com|e2
name3|uname3|user2@mail.com|e2
name4|uname4|user4@mail.com|e2
```

The awk command used is:

```
echo "$OUTPUT" | awk -v OFS='|' '{split($0,a,": ")} \
    /^sn:/{sn=a[2]} \
    /^uid:/{uid=a[2]} \
    /^mail:/{mail=a[2]} \
    /^roomNumber:/{room=a[2]; print sn, uid, mail, room}'
```

Is there a way to handle a missing attribute such as mail in the example above please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you notice, your input is very well structured in records. Each record is separated by a set of blank lines. You can exploit this with awk.

The idea in the following is to read each multi-line record which has key-value pairs of the form (`key: value`)

```
sn: name2
uid: uname2
mail: user2@mail.com
roomNumber: e2
```

We will tell awk to extract that information accordingly and store it in an array `data`. We will then use this array to rebuild the data in the way you want. If a key does not exist in the record, it will return a empty value when requested:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS=""; FS="\n"; OFS="|"}
     { delete data; }
     { for(i=1;i<=NF;++i) {
          match($i,/: +/);
          key=substr($i,1,RSTART-1); value=substr($i,RSTART+RLENGTH);
          data[key]=value }
     }
     { print data["sn"], data["uid"], data["mail"], data["roomNumber"] }' file
```

This method is very generic and extremely flexible if you want to change anything later on.

On the presented example, this outputs:

```
name1|uname1|user1@mail.com|e2
name2|uname2|user2@mail.com|e2
name3|uname3||e2
name4|uname4|user4@mail.com|e2
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your input lines per record are always ordered as shown and it's only the email field that could ever be missing:

```
$ awk -v RS= -F': |\n' -v OFS='|' '{print $2, $4, (NF>6 ? $6 : ""), $NF}' file
name1|uname1|user1@mail.com|e2
name2|uname2|user2@mail.com|e2
name3|uname3||e2
name4|uname4|user4@mail.com|e2
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set the vars to the empty string after printing:

```
$ awk -v OFS='|' '{split($0,a,": ")} 
    /^sn:/{sn=a[2]} 
    /^uid:/{uid=a[2]} 
    /^mail:/{mail=a[2]} 
    /^roomNumber:/{room=a[2]; print sn, uid, mail, room; sn=uid=mail=room=""}' file

name1|uname1|user1@mail.com|e2
name2|uname2|user2@mail.com|e2
name3|uname3||e2
name4|uname4|user4@mail.com|e2
```

Comment: awk does field splitting for you, you don't need to call split(). Just add `-F': '` up front and then use `$2` instead of `a[2]`. Obviously this will fail if/when the `roomNumber` attribute is the one that's missing so YMMV.

Comment: I've found a bug with this solution that I'm struggling to fix.
If I just have the following input with roomNumber missing:
`echo "$OUTPUT"
sn: name4
uid: uname4
mail: user4@mail.com`
It doesn't show the line at all. Any ideas why this may be happening please?

Comment: It's happening because you only print when you arrive to the line that starts with "roomNumber". As Ed Morton points out in the comment, above, this solution fails when the roomNumber attribute is missing.

Comment: The solution from @kvantour is more general and will work well no matter which attribute may be missing.

Comment: ahh yes sorry, I missed Ed's comments for some reason. I will implement @kvantour's solution instead. Many thanks!